# Message passing to database as well as to producer side(jms) parallely in spring integration

Tags: spring-integration, activemq-classic

Am doing a sample project on spring integration with (jms)activemq. Requirement is to store data to database and pass that data to a queue in activemq both should work  parallely. Am getting an error while sending message to producer side like   **"nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Target object of type [class userDetails.web.QkaapzzMessageProducer] has no eligible methods for handling Messages. "**

```
    <int:publish-subscribe-channel id="postChannel" />      
    <jms:inbound-channel-adapter id="jmsIn"
        destination="helloWorldJMSQueue"
        channel="postChannel"
        extract-payload="false" 
        auto-startup="true">
        <int:poller fixed-delay="3000" />
     </jms:inbound-channel-adapter>                                     
 <jms:message-driven-channel-adapter id="helloWorldJMSAdapater" destination="helloWorldJMSQueue" connection-factory="jmsConnectionFactory"
    channel="postChannel" />


<integration:service-activator id="helloWorldServiceActivator" input-channel="postChannel" 
ref="qkaapzzMessageProducer" method="sendMessage" output-channel="nullChannel" />                                                                                                       


<int:channel id="requestChannel" />
<int:channel id="outputChannel" />

<int-http:inbound-gateway request-channel="requestChannel"
reply-channel="outputChannel" supported-methods="GET" path="/register"
view-name="register">
<int-http:request-mapping />
</int-http:inbound-gateway>
<int-http:inbound-gateway request-channel="postChannel"
reply-channel="outputChannel" supported-methods="POST" path="/registerNew"
error-channel="errorChannel" view-name="login">
</int-http:inbound-gateway>



<int-jdbc:outbound-channel-adapter 
    query="insert into user_registration (USER_FSTNAME,USER_ADDRESS,USER_STATE,USER_CITY,USER_OCCUPATION,USER_EMAIL,USER_CONTACT,USER_PASSWORD) 
values (:fstName,:addrss,:state,:city,:occupation,:email,:contact,:password)"
    channel="postChannel" data-source="dataSource" id="sample" sql-parameter-source-factory="spelSource"  />


<int:service-activator  ref="userService" input-channel="requestChannel"
                             output-channel="outputChannel"  method="message"/>

<bean id="spelSource"
    class="org.springframework.integration.jdbc.ExpressionEvaluatingSqlParameterSourceFactory">
    <property name="parameterExpressions">
        <map>                                                                                                                           
            <entry key="fstName" value="payload[firstName]" />
            <entry key="lstName" value="payload[lastName]" />
            <entry key="addrss" value="payload[address]" />
            <entry key="state" value="payload[state]" />                
            <entry key="city" value="payload[city]" />
            <entry key="occupation" value="payload[occupation]" />
            <entry key="email" value="payload[email]"/>
            <entry key="contact" value="payload[contact]"/>
            <entry key="password" value="payload[password]"/>
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

My producer class

```
public class QkaapzzMessageProducer {
private Connection connection;
private Session session;
private javax.jms.MessageProducer messageProducer;
public static final String HELLO_WORLD_QUEUE = "testQueue";
public Message<?> sendMessage(Message<?> msg,String queue2) throws 
JMSException {

    if((queue2.equals("")) ||(queue2.equals(null)) )
    {   
        queue2=HELLO_WORLD_QUEUE;
        session =
            connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        Queue queue = session.createQueue(queue2);
        messageProducer = session.createProducer(queue);
       // TextMessage txt = session.createTextMessage(text);
        messageProducer.send((javax.jms.Message) msg);
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     }
    else      
    {
    session =connection.createSession(false, 
    Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
    Queue queue = session.createQueue(queue2);
    messageProducer = session.createProducer(queue);
    messageProducer.send((javax.jms.Message) msg);
        }
    return msg;
}
}
```

Also i need to pass that message from queue to the consumer. Am new to this all and help me to find a solution

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't clear, because the problem you show is not related to the subject of the question.

Your exception says that the `sendMessage()` method signature doesn't fit to the Messaging model.

It there like:

```
public Message<?> sendMessage(Message<?> msg, String queue2) throws
```

Spring Integration is based on the `Message<?>` objects exchange. So, when Service Activator tries to call that method it has only a request `Message<?>` in hands and fully doesn't know what is that `queue2` argument and what to do with that.

You can help it a bit placing a `@Header` annotation on that `queue2` argument. Of course, it is going to work if you really have that info in the message headers.

See more info in the [Reference Manual](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.5.RELEASE/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#service-activator).